# Rails 4 : arel_table.maximum.descでソートを行うときエラー発生

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql

多対多関係のOrderモデルとProductモデルを持っていて、

一つのorderは複数のproductsと紐付いています。

orderを持っているproductsの中で一番値段の高いproductの価格を見て、orderをソートしたいです。

自分が書いたコードはこんな感じです:
`@orders = Order.group(arel_table[:id]).order(Product.arel_table[:price].maximum)`

こうやって昇順のソートはうまく行けましたが、以下のように降順でordersをソートをかけると
`@orders = Order.group(arel_table[:id]).order(Product.arel_table[:price].maximum.desc)`

こんなエラーメッセージが返された : 
``` undefined method ``desc' for #<Arel::Nodes::Max:0x007fb2ab9104a0> ```

降順にソートするにはどう書けばいいですか？

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32517474/rails-4-error-when-trying-to-sort-by-using-arel-table-maximum-desc
↑英語のstackoverflowにも質問してます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLが2回発行されますが、こんな感じで実現できるのでは？

```
order_ids = Order.joins(:products).group('orders.id').order('maximum_products_price desc').maximum('products.price').keys
sanitized_query = ActiveRecord::Base.send(:sanitize_sql_array, ["field(id, ?)", order_ids])
Order.order(sanitized_query)
```

集計処理が絡むSELECTはActiveRecordとあまり相性が良くないのでクエリを分けたり、生SQLを書いたりして、コードのスマートさをあえて捨てた方が素早く実装できる気がします。

参考: [Rails - MySQL+ActiveRecordで、与えられた配列順にorderしたい時 - Qiita](http://qiita.com/chezou/items/8c0481044c954c4bca3b)

#### EDIT

Arelで完結させるのであれば、こんなふうに書けそうです。

```ruby
@orders = Order
            .group(arel_table[:id]) # Order.arel_table[:id] の間違い？
            .order(Arel::Nodes::Descending.new(Product.arel_table[:price].maximum))
```

上のコードはArelのコードを参考にしています。

[Module: Arel::OrderPredications — Documentation for rails/arel (master)](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/arel/Arel/OrderPredications#desc-instance_method)

試してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございました！
rails的なarel_tableの書き方でうまく行きました！